# FCGX_Accept_r returns success without valid Request

Tags: c, fastcgi

This is the related code, I shorted it as much as possible hopefully not excluding the error source.

DebugLogMsg is a printf like log file writing tool which can be considered as not causing the error.

```
//Some init stuff and smthng
    while (1)
    {
        memset (&requestFcgx, 0, sizeof (requestFcgx));
        iRet = FCGX_InitRequest (&requestFcgx, 0, 0);
        DebugLogMsg ("FCGX_InitRequest() called!!\r\n");

        if (iRet != 0)
        {
            DebugLogMsg ("FCGX_InitRequest failed, return val:%d!\r\n", iRet);
            return NULL;
        }

        iRet = FCGX_Accept_r (&requestFcgx);

        if (iRet != 0)
        {
            DebugLogMsg1 ("FCGX_Accept_r failed!\r\n");
            continue;
        }

        char *foo = FCGX_GetParam("SOME_CUSTOM_VAL", requestFcgx.envp);
        DebugLogMsg ("CustomParam:%s\r\n", foo);

        do
        {
            //processing the request...
            if (ERROR == TRUE)
            {
                DebugLogMsg ("FatalError!\r\n");
                return NULL;
            }

            DebugLogMsg ("no errors occured!");
        }
        while (0);

        FCGX_Finish_r (&requestFcgx);
        DebugLogMsg ("Cleanup.... DONE!\r\n");
    }
```

My problem is `iRet = FCGX_Accept_r (&requestFcgx);` doesn't block every 2nd call, as it should. (at least I expect this function to it should be blocking)

As soon a request is sent by the webserver the Function releases, runs through the loop without any errors getting logged, calls the Finish, loops to the start of the loop body and when calling  `iRet = FCGX_Accept_r (&requestFcgx);` again, it returns instantly with `iRet == 0` but the `requestFcgx` structure seems to be invalid (what is to be expected as there was not even an aditional request initiated). The corresponding Log File contains for this process:

```
[Wed Apr 15 15:41:26 2015][Thread:0;0x802420040]    FCGX_InitRequest() called!
            ----------------------------------------
[Wed Apr 15 15:41:26 2015][Thread:0;0x802420040]    CustomParam:ExpectedStuff
[Wed Apr 15 15:41:26 2015][Thread:0;0x802420040]    no errors occured!
[Wed Apr 15 15:41:26 2015][Thread:0;0x802420040]    Cleanup.... DONE!

[Wed Apr 15 15:41:26 2015][Thread:0;0x802420040]    FCGX_InitRequest() called!
            ----------------------------------------
[Wed Apr 15 15:41:26 2015][Thread:0;0x802420040]    CustomParam:(null)
[Wed Apr 15 15:41:26 2015][Thread:0;0x802420040]    FatalError!

//////////////////////////////
////////Protocol closed///////
//////////////////////////////
```

(Please someone edit the Logtext to be not formated as code, I don't know how to)

The Fatal error occures as the Request doesn't provide information and get shut down. the point is, why `iRet = FCGX_Accept_r (&requestFcgx);` returns with `0` when it obvisiously failed? And in how far I have to consider this behaving, if it is expected to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues -

1. `FCGX_InitRequest(&requestFcgx, 0, 0)` needs to be called before entering the `while(1)` loop.
2. SIGPIPE signal can also cause this behaviour. Try ignoring it. Add this block to the start of your `main()` function -

   ```
   struct sigaction sa_ign;
   sa_ign.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
   sa_ign.sa_flags = 0;
   sigemptyset(&sa_ign.sa_mask);
   sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa_ign, NULL);
   ```

You mentioned that the app is multi-threaded. If so, you must also call `FCGX_Init()`. Below is information from `fcgiapp.h` header file -

```
/*
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * FCGX_Init --
 *
 *      Initialize the FCGX library.  Call in multi-threaded apps
 *      before calling FCGX_Accept_r().
 *
 *      Returns 0 upon success.
 *
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
DLLAPI int FCGX_Init(void);
```

Check this simple multi-threaded FastCGI application -

http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/threaded.c

Comment: so `FCGX_InitRequest(&requestFcgx, 0, 0)` isn't the counter part to `FCGX_Finish_r (&requestFcgx)`? So `FCGX_Finish_r (&requestFcgx)` isn't cleaning anything up, that needs to be reinitialized?

Comment: It is Well to know, but sadly didn't fixed the problem. Is it important to know that the `while(1)` is run in multiple pthreads? I put the code in front of my `main()` as you had stated.

Comment: FCXG_Finish_r() releases resources allocated by FCGX_Accept_r() and should be called at end  of the While(1) loop or before the "continue" statement.

Comment: If your FCGI loop is in a thread then FCGX_InitRequest() should be in the thread function and not in the main() function. You can call FCGX_InitRequest() just before the while(1) loop.

Comment: I don't see you call FCGX_Init() which must be called in multi-threaded apps. I updated my answer this info about FCGX_Init(). Please check

Comment: You don't see me calling ` FCGX_Init` in the snippet, as it is the snippet of the process, whilest I'm calling  `FCGX_Init` already in the main. Or do I have to call `FCGX_Init` in each thread?

Comment: You need to call FCGX_Init() in each fast cgi thread where you call FCGX_Accept_r().

Comment: Is there any relevance of the order in which I'm calling `FCGX_InitRequest (&requestFcgx, 0, 0);` and `FCGX_Init()` ? After my last change under respect to your comment I'm now calling both inside of the thread before entering the `while(1)` and I'm calling `FCGX_Init()` immediate followed by `FCGX_InitRequest (&requestFcgx, 0, 0);` but there isn't any change in behaving yet.

Comment: I found one example for you try - http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/threaded.c